# What is the best way to remap mouse events in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, winapi, mouse

I need to **catch and cancel any drag-and-drop event**, and instead **trigger a normal click** on the initial coordinates where the mouse was clicked.

This is to help a disabled person with loss of motor function. Whenever she clicks on something, she keeps the button pressed and moves, registering a drag-and-drop event instead of a click.

I already tried software solutions (SteadyMouse, X-Mouse Button Control) but to no avail. Behavior modification is no longer an option due to her dementia.

I'm a webdev so not very familiar with Windows programming but I'm willing to learn if it can help her. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: How is this any different than your previous question, which I commented on earlier? Which I can't find now, did you delete it and start over asking the exact same question again?

Comment: Sorry Remy: initially, my question asked where to hire a developper for that, so the mods removed it and marked it Closed. I edited the question to ask how to do it (which you commented) but it was still marked Closed. I was unsure if it was visible again: that's why I started over from scratch. Could you repost your comment please? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: `she keeps the button pressed and moves,`   Will the mouse remain in the unreleased state? If so, it is difficult to determine when the user clicks the mouse next time. For example, the user wants to continue to click on another target while dragging.

Comment: Thanks, Strive Sun. She does release the mouse after a second or two, but by that time, the pointer is way off the initial target.

Comment: After the user presses the left button of the mouse, `SendInput` is used to simulate the release of the mouse, so that there is no need to wait for the user to manually release the left button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you can immediately return to the release message event when the user presses the left mouse button.

Using [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) and mouse hook,

C++ code sample,

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

HHOOK MouseHook;

BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(_In_ DWORD dwCtrlType) 
{
    if (dwCtrlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHook);
    }
    return 1;
}

LRESULT __stdcall MouseHookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    INPUT input{};
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{
    if (!(MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookCallback, NULL, 0)))
    {
        cout << "Failed to install MouseHook hook!" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine, 1);
    
    SetHook();
    MSG msg;
    
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

**Updated:**

Here is quick [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyiPb.jpg) demo and I have updated part of the code.

Newly added code:

```
BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(_In_ DWORD dwCtrlType) 
{
    if (dwCtrlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHook);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This callback function will be called when you close the console window, and the function contains the unhook code.

Note: After installing the hook, you need to uninstall the hook if you not need it. If you don't uninstall the hook in time, it will cause mouse stuck.

With this app, drag events will be blocked because the mouse will receive a release event immediately after it is pressed.

Comment: Wow; thanks so much for the code! From the very little I understand about desktop programming, I should paste that code in some kind of compiler, to produce an EXE I could run? Is there one available online? Sorry to be such a dunce.

Comment: @Kerans You can use [VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) to produce the exe.  Since the generation of exe relies on various libraries, there is no suitable online tool for you to use. For the use of C++ code in VS2019, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=msvc-160) can help you get started quickly.

Comment: @Kerans I am not sure which programming language and compilation tool you are good at. But I can be sure that [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) and [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) in winapi are what you need.

Comment: Sun Thanks, I installed VS2019 with C++ support. Upon starting, it asks what kind of project I need (Console app, Desktop, DLL, etc.) Which one is best for the code you provided?

Comment: @Kerans See my updated. You can use console app or empty project.

Comment: @strive-sun-msft OMG, this is fantastic! I was able to compile the program and it works exactly like I needed! I'm going to install it on my Mom's computer ASAP (along with TaskbarHide so she cannot see it) and she'll be able to use the computer again! If there's any way I can tangibly show you my appreciation, please let me know! You've been so generous and patient. A million thanks!

Comment: @Kerans Glad to help you:)